# JQuery touchpunch draggable laggy on android device

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, draggable

I have used the draggable jquery of touchpunch: http://touchpunch.furf.com/ in my phonegap application for my android phone. I uploaded pictures of objects to drag over a picture. But whatever object I try to drag it always seems laggy, while on my iphone it works perfectly fine without lag. This has been tested on a Desire HD and Samsung Galaxy S2 so not the slowest types of android phones. Does anyone have an idea what is causing it and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: dealing with a very similar issue on newer android devices using touchpunch and jquery-ui slider elements... works fine everywhere else (browsers + ios) but performance is terrible borderline not usable on android.  anyone have any light to shed on this one? thanks in advance

Comment: Also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `position : absolute` for the element? This can increase performance greatly because anything with `position : relative` being animated/moved requires a redraw of the whole page (since ancestors and descendants can be affected by any changes). Using `position : absolute` only requires a redraw of the region that the element takes-up (so anything in-front or behind the element and the element itself).

I tested the demo page on my Droid X (almost two years old now) and it functioned fine, but it is a simple test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It didn't work though, same laggyness. It seems to drag behind your finger.